# How to use the Hurd kernel in a Debian installation?

Tags: kernel, hurd

I am running a Debian (Jessie so far) and would like to give the Hurd kernel a go. How could I swap the Linux kernel for it? After that, would the developers be interested in any sort of feedback about how it's working for me?

Answer (score 2):

You can’t just swap the kernel, Debian Hurd is a different architecture so you need to use a separate installation. If you do test it, I’m sure the developers would be interested in your feedback (installation reports etc.).

Answer (score 0):

From the GNU/Hurd front page:

> The Debian project has committed to provide such a binary distribution.
>   Debian GNU/Hurd is currently under development and available in the
>   unstable  branch of the Debian archive.

Regarding feedback, I bet it is welcome if it comes through the appropriate channels, namely their bug tracker.
In the FAQ they say literally that you should not ask any questions before trying to answer them yourself extensively.